# CSS Class not changing when using ASP:RANGEVALIDATOR on TextBox

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, textbox, rangevalidator

PLEASE help me! I've been banging my head for days because of this one thing.

I have a TextBox with a RangeValidator. I need to change the color of all my Textboxes in a page; using javascript it's working for all of them except by the one with the RangeValidator

When I remove the RangeValidator the color shows up as intended, but I can't remove the extender because I need it to validate my control

I can change it when I run the program and go on F12 but the same property doesn't work when I set it on my code. This control is going throught the same empty validation as the one above it, but the background color only changes once I remove the RangeValidator:

[Two controls going through the same validation; only the one without the RangeValidator works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbKfw.png)

[My aspx for the TextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkagO.png)

[The javascript code I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdjv2.png)